# Passing password from scheduled task to WGET --proxy-password argument?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, password, scheduled-task, wget

I am trying to set up a daily scheduled download of files from an external web-server, using `WGET`, Windows' task-scheduler and command-scripts.

Since `WGET` will be run on a server from within the company's internal network, it has to first connect through our HTTP-proxy server, which requires proxy-authentication (HTTP 407), and then when the external web-server is reached, it too also requires authentication (HTTP 401), before the files can be downloaded.

Now this all works, using the following command-line, which unfortunatly contains visible passwords in the command-script:

```
wget.exe -e http_proxy=http://company-proxy:80
         --proxy-user=PROXYUSER --proxy-password=PROXYPASSWORD 
         --http-user=HTTPUSER --http-password=HTTPPASSWORD
         "http://www.example.com/folder/FileToDownload.txt"
```

Since the scheduled-task, that is starting `WGET` (or command-script), has to *run as* `PROXYUSER` with `PROXYPASSWORD`, I was wondering if it is possible to somehow read or give these values to the `--proxy..` arguments of `WGET`, and not having them in plain sight within the command-line/-script?

E.g.

```
wget.exe --proxy-user=<Get_User_From_ScheduledTask> 
         --proxy-password=<Get_Password_From_ScheduledTask>
         ...
```

Or alternatively, from a Windows command-script, is there a way to "programmatically read" values (stored in some kind of registry-database or "vault"), that only the *run as* user will have access to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think wgetrc will solve your problem.

look [here](http://pages.interlog.com/~tcharron/wgetwin.html) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Wgetrc-Syntax).

Comment: Hmm yes, I guess an ACL protected wgetrc file, passed as parameter from the scheduled task to WGET, would be the proper solution.